# Perform calculation and update a valuein mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to add a specific number to the current value and update the same in that field. How can I do this?
[image: Refer Screenshot]

In the picture, the created field has a value 600. I want to add 200 to 600 and store it back in the db. If it was just one I would use `$set`. But I have 10000 documents and each "created" has a unique document. I Need to get the value of "created" and add some number to it and store it back.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? 'Please help me' is not working without any effort.

Comment: See-https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I was trying $set earlier. But that  was not of help. It would set the value of "created" to a new value specified. But $inc really helped.